# How should I add events when using iron-router and meteor?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

Before using iron-router I attached events using:

```
Template.templatename.events = {};
```

With iron-router, you pass data through the data attribute in the route, and generally don't touch the global Template object... so where should I put events?
Should I continue to use Template.tempaltename.events?

Are you supposed to use the global Template object in conjunction with iron-router?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You confuse two things: template "class" and template "instance". With `Template.name.events` you create global behavior of the application: how given templates is rendered, how it reacts to data, to user events.

The data you send with router is attached to a given template *instance*, that is the single DOM node related object that is displayed on the web page.

So yes, you should still use `Template.name.events`, as well as you can use `Template.name.rendered`, `.created`, `.deleted`, `.customDataHelper` and so on.

---

By the way, it's better to use the full version of the `events`:

```
Template.name.events({
   ...
});
```

It saves you from a few problems in the long run.

Comment: Hubert, I tend to use the first syntax.  What kinds of problems stem from the second?

Comment: I am also curious about what Jim asked.

Comment: @JimMack I think the first one is deprecated.

Comment: Imagine a big project with several developers. When you use `Template.name.events = {}`, and then another dev starts working on the same template in another place, your events will get erased in the best case. Or you'll get runtime errors - I've seen such in a not so big project, and they were not obvious to track. If you use the proper form `Template.name.events({})` instead, everything will work smoothly.

Comment: Thanks.  I get the overwriting of the whole method.  To clarify, I thought the syntax under discussion was Template.name.specificHelper = function () {}.  And @BenjaminRH is probably right.  I like it because it's less typing, more sugar.

Comment: I'm surprised the = version even exists. So the two forms are not equivalent as one replaces, while the other appends.
Thanks :)

Comment: @JasonMcCarrell As I said, the = version was the original. It has since been deprecated, and you are encouraged to use the second version.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I'd continue to attach events like that. Iron router doesn't really change the way the UI works. However, I'd keep an eye for updates, because the new Meteor UI the dev team is working on will be ready probably within the next month or two, at which point this will all change anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up about that. I figured something like this may be in the works... Meteor is at 0.6.5... pretty young ;)